# How do I install Glippy?

Tags: unity, 11.10, indicator, glippy

I just installed the brand new 11.10 and apparently the ppa for glippy don't work with oneiric. Maybe with the upgrade glippy can still be operating with you? thnx

Answer (score 1):

**The PPA has been updated!** - Now you can [find packages for Oneiric](https://launchpad.net/~bikooo/+archive/glippy?field.series_filter=oneiric), too.

[image]

If you don't know how to install that/a PPA (in Ubuntu 11.10), please read the answer(s) of this UA question:

- ["What are PPAs and how do I use them?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/40351#40351)

**to install**
you can install install **Glippy**...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bikooo/glippy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install glippy glippy-ubuntu-mono

sudo gconf-schemas --unregister glippy.schemas
sudo gconf-schemas --register glippy-indicator.schemas
```

[source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/glippy-clipboard-manager-gets-files-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the [Glippy PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bikooo/+archive/glippy) and it seems that there is not yet a package for 11.10 yet.

If the project is active, they they should be up within a few weeks.

If you try to upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10, the older glippy package might work for you, but is not recommended.

If you want to do so in a fresh install, you can add the PPA, then edit the source to point to natty. Go to Dash -> Software Sources -> Choose your PPA -> Edit

[image: Imgur]

In my case it did not work, though, and I had to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bikooo-glippy-oneiric.list` file manually.

To do that, Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bikooo-glippy-oneiric.list` to launch gedit with the file. Replace the text oneiric with natty and save.

Of course you will need to run an update after this.

Comment: hi Capt.Nemo, thank you for you answer, I will try to edit the source list.